# Backbone.js and regex routing

Tags: regex, backbone.js, url-routing

Is it possible to register a route for `/pages/*url` but not for `/pages/*url/edit/` where URL can be something like this `foo/bar/and-so-on`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[router.route](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) supports using a regex natively.

```
initialize: function(options) {

  // Matches /117-a/b/c/open, passing "117-a/b/c" to this.open
  this.route(/^(.*?)\/open$/, "open");

},

open: function(id) { ... }
```

Comment: Should't this work or is it something wrong with my regex? `[/^pages\/(.*?)[^new]$/, 'pages', this.pages]` I want it to use the pages route for all urls starting with pages/some/slugs/ but not for urls that ends with /new