# Backbone.js router callback to fire on all URL segments except 1 specific url segment

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, pushstate

I'm creating my first application that uses the Backbonejs router.

> http://backbonejs.org/#Router

I'm curious, is it possible to define a route that will fire for every url segment except one?

In my case, I don't want this callback to fire if the url is `http://www.example.com/login`, but I do want it to fire for

- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/foo
- http://www.example.com/bar
- etc.

My router looks like this:

```
var SuiteRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // ################################ Defined Routes ################################
    routes: {
        "":      "landing",     //Suite primary page, initiates menus and other suite-wide items, initiated everywhere except login
        "login": "login"
    },

    // ########################### Route Callbacks ################################
    landing: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log('landing');
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log(arguments); //<--- nothing useful, empty array
        console.log('login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270840/backbone-js-and-regex-routing?rq=1)?

Comment: Haven't you tried this?
`routes:{
"login":"login",
"*":"landing"
}` the difference it makes is routes are called based on precedence of matches. Here if we provide * as first root it will be called for all the routes regardless of login, foo, bar. But we do want `login` right? so we give precedence to login route by pushing it up the definition ladder.Now it works :) go enjoy the hot cut of chocolate

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
var SuiteRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // ################################ Defined Routes ################################
    routes: {
        "":      "landing",     //Suite primary page, initiates menus and other suite-wide items, initiated everywhere except login
        "login": "login"
    },

    // ########################### Route Callbacks ################################
    landing: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        console.log('landing');
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log(arguments); //<--- nothing useful, empty array
        console.log('login');
    }
});

var router = new Router();
router.on("route", function(route, params) {
console.log(route); //will be called every route change in addition to the appropriate other callbacks.
if(route!=="login") {
//do something
}
});
```